# How to render docx using flying saucer

Tags: java, pdf, docx, flying-saucer

Is it possible to render as docx instead of pdf using flying saucer?

I can't find any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, flying-saucer only outputs PDF and images. It doesn't render docx documents.

Comment: I found out so i used a library to convert pdf to docx and it's fine